# Typesafe Activator Build Hangs

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, typesafe-activator

I'm following the book [Learning Akka](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010V8SICW). I've checked out the [source code](https://github.com/jasongoodwin/learning-akka) via GitHub. I open the project in Typesafe Activator and try to compile, but the build reaches a point where it hangs indefinitely and I'm not sure why. It gets stuck here:

```
> server-post-command-cleanup
> server-handle-next-server-request
```

Entire Build log: http://pastebin.com/WR703TKp

What can I do to begin reasoning about the problem? Why is it hanging there and what can I do to fix it?